# How to center align a pre tag in HTML

Tags: html, center, pre

I'm trying to post some code on a blog using the pre tag. Something like this:

`void function(){return 0;}`

Now I want all this code to be center aligned. I'm not talking just about the text but also about the border around it. The width is set currently to 60%. So I want all of this to be center aligned. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a custom CSS `<div>` Class that sets font to `courier` (10pt) and has left and right margins set in so that it's centered on the page.

```
.code {
  font-family:courier;
  font-size: 10pt;
  margin: 5px; border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Then call it as follows:

```
<div class="code">Your Code Here</div>
```

The magic happens in the `margin` section. You can set all 4 attributes, but if you just set one, then it [makes it a margin of that size all the way around](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/margin.php).

Comment: Left and right margins set as auto, with a fixed width for the div should do this nicely.

Comment: Better use the generic “monospace” than the specific “courier”.

Comment: Use of the CODE element would be good here. Either inside the div, or make the CODE element display:block and replace the div with it.